# Applying SUM() to column with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(new_cases) AS new_cases,
    SUM(COALESCE(CAST(new_deaths AS REAL), 0)) AS total_deaths,
    SUM(COALESCE(CAST(new_deaths AS REAL), 0)) / SUM(new_cases) * 100 AS DeathsPercentage
FROM
    PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths
WHERE
    continent IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    date
ORDER BY
    date, new_cases
```

and get the following error:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

I think the error originated from the null values in the new_cases column these null values could be ignored or transformed to 0 like I tried to do with the `coalesce()` function, but still gives me the error.

Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Thats not an error, its a warning.

Comment: It's not a big deal when you see this message, your code will continue as usual. In your example, perhaps new_cases can also be NULL? It should help to wrap it inside ISNULL(new_cases, 0). The bigger problem is, why are you using REAL datatype? It's a bit strange, for your case NUMERIC(19,1) should be better.